# jquery serialize() on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know that some IEs have a URL limit equal to 2038. I've seen that the `serialize()` jquery function is transforming the content of a form into something similar to an URL. In the end, this result will be attached to the URL.

The question is what happens if I have, let's say, 2 MB of data to submit?

Is this jquery function doing something to prevent those kind of issues?

Comment: Seems like you'd just switch to POST in such a case.

Comment: Isn't POST referring to the body?

Comment: When a `<form>` uses the POST method, or when you do an ajax request with POST, then the query string (the result of `.serialize()`) is part of the HTTP request content, not part of the URL. There's no size limit. (Well there probably is, but it's more likely to be a server limit and it's much larger.)